# Solve PDE $u_{t} = u_{xx} + u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need help for solve the PDE:

$u_{t} = u_{xx} +u,  \ \ \ \  0<x<L , \ \ t>0$

$u(0,t)=1 , \ \ \ \ \     u(pi,t)=2, \ \  t>0$

$u(x,0)=sin(3x)$

I know who to solve the equation without $+u$, but with $+u$ I'm lost....

thanks for your help...

Edit:

Suposing that $u(x,t) = w(x,t) + v(x)$ so

$$u_t(x,t) = w_t(x,t) \ \  \text{and} \\   u_{xx}(x,t) = w_{xx}(x,t) + v_{xx}(x)$$

Then $$u_{t} = u_{xx} +u \rightarrow $$

$$w_t = w_{xx} + v_{xx} + w + v = (w_{xx} + w) + (v_{xx} + v)$$

I need that $v_{xx} + v = 0$ and satisfy my BC, so

$$v(0) = 1  \ \ \text{and} \ \  v(\pi) = 2$$

If I choose $v(0) = 1 \rightarrow v(x)= Asin(x) + cos(x)$

If I choose $v(\pi) = 2$ $\rightarrow v(x)= Asin(x) -2cos(x)$

I can't have them both at same time....

Comment: Use separation of variables.

Comment: Please include the PDE in the OP. If the link becomes a dead link, your question cannot be understood anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Use the substitution $v = e^{-t}u$. Then $$v_t = -e^{-t}u + e^{-t}u_t$$ and $$v_{xx} = e^{-t}u_{xx}.$$ Thus $$v_t - v_{xx} = e^{-t}(u_t - u - u_{xx}) = 0.$$ That is, $v_t = v_{xx}$ and you have reduced the problem to one that you say you can solve.

Comment: May I ask how you thought of this substitution? Is it a classical one?

Comment: In a way it is: it is very reminiscent of the integrating factor method (which is used to solve first order linear ODEs). Here, you're essentially using an integrating factor in time while leaving the spatial variables unaffected.

Comment: That's a smart substitution! +1

Comment: And the boundary condition and initial conditions? 

I don’t need to transform the IC and BC? Like $w(0,t)= w(pi, t) = 0$.

Because is a inhomogeneus BC, and a general solution u(x, t) is the sum of the steady solution $v(x)$ and a transient solution $w(x, t), u(x, t) = v(x) + w(x, t)$. The transient solution $w(x, t)$ satisfies a homogeneous IBVP with zero boundary conditions.

Comment: The BC and IC transform exactly how you'd expect. For example: $$v(x,0) = e^{-0}u(x,0) = 1 \cdot \sin(3x) = \sin(3x)$$ and $$v(0,t) = e^{-t}u(0,t) = e^{-t} \cdot 1 = e^{-t}.$$

Comment: Hmm... But the second BC: $v(\pi, t)= e^{- \pi }u(\pi, t) = e^{- \pi } \cdot 2 =  2e^{- \pi }.$

How I calculate the steady solution?

Answer (score 2):

You want to solve $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.$$

Suppose $u(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$. Then we get $$T'(t)X(x)=T(t)X''(x)+T(t)X'(x).$$
Dividing by $T(t)X(x)$ yields $$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{X'(x)}{X(x)}.$$
Since the left-hande side depends only on $t$ and the right-hand side only $x$, we may conclude that there exists a constant $C$ such that $$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{X'(x)}{X(x)}=C.$$

Let's solve $\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=C$ first. We get $\ln(T(t))'=C$ and thus $T(t)=C_1e^{t}$. Similarly you can solve the second order equation. Using the boundary condition you can impose a condition on $C$ that will help you to solve the equation. General theory will tell you that you write the general solution as a series in the eigen solutions obtained in this way.

Off course, the other answer is a much smarter approach which requires less work!